# Integrating salesforce org with php Site

Tags: integration

-> As I am new to salesforce and currently i did the integration of salesforce org with php site using Enterprise WSDL and what are records are inserted in php site will come in salesforce and what are records are inserted in salesforce will get in php site.

-> And in client php site there are several user among them i mention above about one user.

-> But now client requirements is that if other user create their profile in php site and his having salesforce org then by entering their api, username, password and token in php site should get automatically integrate with their salesforce org and it behaves the same like i mention above scenario.

Is it possible? if its possible then can you plz share it any example how to do this?Any Steps

Any help will be grateful

Thanks for you any feedback....